# How to import context from a file which is 2-steps up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, import

This is my folder hierarchy-

SRC -

```
/assets
/components
App.jsx
```

COMPONENTS -

```
/screens/Login.jsx
Carousel.jsx
Navbar.jsx
```

Suppose I am in the `Login.jsx` file. From there how will I import a context which was declared in `App.jsx`

When I start writing this code -

```
import React from 'react';
import { IsLoggedInContext } from '../'
```

The autocompletes in vscode editor I get are -

- Carousel
- Navbar
- Screens

When I start using `.../` no autocomplete comes for the `App` file and it doesn't also work if I manually write this code -

```
import { isLoggedInContext } from '.../App'
```

So, how will I import the context in the `Login.jsx` file? Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `.` is the current directory, a double `..` is the parent directory. A triple `...` isn't valid syntax for referencing directory/file structures.

From `src/components/screens`, `".."` gets you into `src/components`, and `"../.."` gets you up another level back to `src`.

```
import { isLoggedInContext } from '../../App';
```